# Find a sequence in a BitVec

Tags: rust, bitvector

I have a large BitVec and I need to find sequences of set/unset bits of an exact length (ie n consective set/unset bits). How can I do that? I have tried `Iterator`s and `for` loops, but I wasn't able to wrap this into a general function.

**UPDATE**:
As requested, more info. The problem is I haven't found a way to

- efficiently find the position of the sequence
- make that into a general function

What I mean by that is that what I was initially researching was of the form `fn find_sequence<A: PartialEq<A>>(v: &[A], value: A, how_many: usize) ...`. Unfortunately, one can't return iterators (because of closures), yet, so that's 1 problem. The second, not being able to efficiently find the position, is that it wasn't clear to me what I'd have to perform in order to achieve what I wanted. Initially, I used `enumerate` to return position-value tuples, then `scan` to be able to find the sequence (ie `if x == val`, update the state and so on). Then I tried using for loops but it was clear to me that I wouldn't be able then make that into a general function (because of `how_many`, which wouldn't allow adding a precise number of if statements for every position, ie `x[0] == val`, `x[1] == val`...).

Comment: Can you share what you _did_ try?

Comment: Oh sorry, I don't have the code anymore. I remember I used `enumerate` and `scan` though

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service. It's expected that you show some amount of effort towards solving your problem and then the community can help get you the last bit of the way. With your question as it currently is, the answer could range from "wrap `fn search() { ... }` around your existing code" to "it's impossible".

Comment: I showed enough amount of effort on IRC (which AFAIK is also "the community"). I think this question is acceptable for this site, if you don't think so please point me to where you think I should add more information along with the page and paragraph in the help center that would make it off-topic or render it unacceptable or not fitting for SO and I will edit it.

Comment: See [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) ("Help others reproduce the problem") as the first thing I found. Note that while there are helpful people everywhere on the Internet, we don't all intimately know each other or what the other group said. What you said on IRC is **completely useless** to the hundreds of developers that will find this question in the future without that context. Helping those developers is as important (or more) as helping you now. If you [edit] your question to include what you have tried, that will help us answer your question and help others in the future learn as well.

Comment: Substring search (in this case a string of bits, with an alphabet of just 0 and 1) requires a *real algorithm* to be efficient, and I suspect this remains true even with just the binary alphabet. So we might need to find an interesting algorithm for this, surely some CS PhD has ran past this problem..

Comment: @Shepmaster Do the edits address your concerns?

Comment: @bluss Interesting perspective, I'm looking at this from a higher-level one though :D

Comment: *“SEARCH of two bit-strings is the hardest sequence function of bit-vectors of all to efficiently implement.”* [H. Baker](http://www.pipeline.com/~hbaker1/BitSearch.html). Maybe because the rest are so easy.

Comment: The high level would be available if the algorithm were already implemented, but it isn't. :-)

Comment: @bluss If the binary alphabet obviated the need for a "real algorithm", other alphabets could just do a search over their bits and filter out misaligned data. They don't, ergo no such obviation exists.

Comment: Is it feasible to implement a suffix array based approach for you? You can find the exact position of your sequences with them: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array